# Trying to make a button appear using variables from another method xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am have created a login button that I would like to only appear when a user has entered characters into the username and password fields. I would like them to appear when the user has at least entered three characters in each field. The problem I am facing is that I am not sure how to go about doing this due to the variables that I need being in another method. Refer to the code snippets below:

```
- (IBAction)logIn:(id)sender {
NSString *username = [self.usernameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *password = [self.passwordField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
// NSString *email = self.emailField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


if ([username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0 /*|| [email length] == 0*/){
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Please enter a username, and password!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}

else {
    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
        else {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }];
}
```

}

In the code above I set up two variables username and password, and I want the following method to take place so that the button will appear if the if statement is met:

```
-(void) showButton {
if ([username length] > 2 && [password length] > 2) {
    logIn.hidden = NO;
}
```

}

However, I dont think the compiler will use the variables from the login method, due to the variables being local variables for that method only. How can i get around this? Also, how would I animate the button, when it shows up? Instead of just having it appear?

Comment: You should be using a text field delegate method to trigger the decision to hide/unhide the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to appear immediately when the conditions are met, add the following to `viewDidLoad` (or whenever you're setting up your textfield).

```
[self.usernameTextField addTarget:self 
                           action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

[self.passwordTextField addTarget:self 
                           action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then, implement the `textFieldDidChange:` method on your view controller.

```
- (void) textFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
    NSString *username = [self.usernameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString *password = [self.passwordField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if ([username length] > 2 && [password length] > 2) 
    {
        logIn.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        login.hidden = YES; //rehide on delete
    }
}
```

This method will be called whenever the user types into the text field.

One note: You're repeating the logic of stripping the whitespace between the two methods where you pull the username and password off the text fields. You could encapsulate that logic into a helper method if you'd like to reduce code duplication.

```
- (NSString*)enteredUsername
{
    return [self.usernameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

Then do a similar method for the password.

You can then call that helper in `textFieldDidChange:`

```
- (void) textFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
    if ([[self enteredUsername] length] > 2 && [[self enteredPassword] length] > 2) 
    {
        logIn.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        login.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your class implement `UITextViewDelegate`, and implement `textViewDidEndEditing:` with your `showButton` logic. Then make sure to set the text field's `delegate` to `self`, so

```
self.username.delegate = self;
self.password.delegate = self;

...

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self showButton];
}
```

Comment: The user could enter 1 character and the button would still show, just as long as the keyboard is dismissed which calls for a bad user experience.

Comment: No, because his `showButton` checks the length of both fields before enabling the button.

Comment: My bad, I thought that was psuedo code.  This method still requires the user to hide the keyboard though.  It'd be much better to use the `Value Changed` event.

Comment: @NRitH where would I set the delegates to self? Would it be in the showButton method?

Comment: @user3413380 Put those calls in `viewDidLoad`.